# flask_mongo_engine how to paginate order by create_time desc?

Tags: mongodb, flask, flask-mongoengine

```
class Session(db.DynamicDocument):
    title = db.StringField(required=False)
    created = db.FloatField(required=True)
    source = db.StringField()

@app.route('/page/<int:page>')
def sessions(page):
    return jsonify(Session.objects.paginate(page=page, per_page=5).items)
```

The response is list of dict which is ordered ASC and first page contains the oldest documents by default.

So how to get the desc order result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [order_by()](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.order_by) before paginate().

> keys may be prefixed with + or - to determine the ordering direction

Just an example:

```
class Session(db.DynamicDocument):
    create_time = db.DateTimeField(required=True)

# clean before test
for i in Session.objects.all():
    i.delete()

for i in range(20):
    create_time = datetime.now()
    create_time = create_time.replace(year=2000 + i)
    ses = Session(create_time=create_time)
    ses.save()

print('2000 -> 2009')
items = Session.objects.order_by('create_time').paginate(page=1, per_page=10).items
for i in items:
    print(i.create_time)

print('2019 -> 2010')
items = Session.objects.order_by('-create_time').paginate(page=1, per_page=10).items
for i in items:
    print(i.create_time)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really helpful ! The -+ shortcuts